# Multiply by 11, regardless of Base

Tags: arithmetic

When I was doing some hexadecimal calculation, I found that a trick that I've known that it exists in decimal arithmetic, also exists in hexadecimal one, that is, the shortcut for **multiplying by 11**.

Here are some examples, multiply some decimals by 11, giving that:
\begin{align*}
11_{10} \times{} 11_{10} &:= 1\ (1+1)\ 1 = 121_{10} \\
62_{10} \times{} 11_{10} &:= 6\ (6+2)\ 2 = 682_{10} \\
65_{10} \times{} 11_{10} &:= 6\ (6+5)\ 5 = 715_{10} \\
78_{10} \times{} 11_{10} &:= 7\ (7+8)\ 8 = 858_{10} \\
\end{align*}

While treating them as hexadecimals, then multiply them by hexadecimal $11_{16}$ as well, giving that:
\begin{align*}
11_{16} \times{} 11_{16} &:= 1\ (1+1)\ 1 = 121_{16} \\
62_{16} \times{} 11_{16} &:= 6\ (6+2)\ 2 = 682_{16} \\
65_{16} \times{} 11_{16} &:= 6\ (6+5)\ 5 = 6\text{B}5_{16} \\
78_{16} \times{} 11_{16} &:= 7\ (7+8)\ 8 = 7\text{F}8_{16} \\
\end{align*}

I don't think this is of a coincidence, there must be a rigorous mathematical proof that supports it. However I have no idea how to prove this kind of things, could anyone give some suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just think about what $11_b$ *means*; it represents $b + 1$. So if you multiply $(\alpha \beta)_b$ by $11_b$, you get precisely $(\alpha b + \beta)(b + 1) = \alpha b^2 + (\alpha + \beta) b + \beta$.

Comment: Can you come up with the rigorous proof for base $10$? If the answer is yes, then you will be able to extend that proof to any base : just change $10$ to the desired base. You can also extend this pattern to $111,1111$ and so on.

Comment: @prets Thanks! A short but thorough explanation, it really helps me getting out of this thing. Could you post it as answer? :)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you for the suggestion! I'm trying to generalize it to other base/factor, just as you said.

Comment: Because radix notation is a *polynomial* function of the radix, you are essentially observing the effect of multiplying a polynomial by $x+1$ (when the digit sums don't carry). For a more interesting example see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3830244/242) on the *multiplicativity* of **reversing the digits**, e.g. $\,12\cdot 13 = 156\Rightarrow 21\cdot 31  = 651\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for clarifying the things. And appreciate that earlier answer for _polynomial reversal_, just give me a new insight into the daily-used *number*s!

Comment: @MichaelLee I have done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment turned answer, on OP's request.

What $11_b$ means in a given base $b$ is the number $b + 1$.
The two "digit" number $\alpha\beta$ in the same base, let's denote it $(\alpha \beta)_b$ similarly means
$$ (\alpha \beta)_b = \alpha b + \beta. $$
Now multiplying these two quantities together and distributing, we get
$$ (\alpha \beta)_b \times 11_b = (\alpha b + \beta)(b + 1) = \alpha b^2 + (\alpha + \beta) b + \beta $$
which, back in base $b$ notation, is then $(\alpha(\alpha+\beta)\beta)_b$ (unless the central "digit" overflows, as noted in some of OP's calculations).

Answer (score 1):

The following is in the base that you are working with

When you take a $2$ digit number $\overline{AB}$ and multiply it with $11$, this is the same as
$$\overline{AB}\cdot (10+1)$$
$$=\overline{AB0}+\overline{AB}$$
$$=A\cdot 100+(A+B)\cdot 10+B$$

You can also get similar results with more digits.